# Approximate a complex measurable function pointwisely almost everywhere by polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, approximation

This is Exercise 13.12 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis:

> Let $f$ be a complex-valued measurable function defined in $\mathbb{C}$. Then there is a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n(z) = f(z)$ almost everywhere.

I and my friend find this exercise interesting. We can prove this for the case $f$ is the characteristic function of a open (or closed) disc. But we don't know how to go further from here. Could anyone give some hints for us?

**Edit**: I give here some of my thoughts:

- At first, we should solve for the case $f$ is the characteristic function of a open dics (or rectangle). **Done**.
- Second, solve for the case $f$ is the characteristic function of a measurable set. (I get stuck at this step.)
- Third, solve for the case $f$ is a combination of two characteristic functions, hence I think the argument will work for a *simple* function. (I still have difficulties here, a polynomial approximates one characteristic function may be very different to another characteristic function.)
- ...

Comment: Are you saying you know how to do it if $f$ is a complex-valued measurable function defined on a bounded domain like $B_R = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < R\}$? If so, you have a polynomial $P_1$ such that $\|f - P_1\|_{B_1} < 1$, a polynomial $P_2$ such that $\|f - P_2\|_{B_2} < 1/2$, and so on. Am I missing something?

Comment: @snarski: No, I just mean $f = \chi_{B_R}$. Indeed, by applying Theorem 13.9 and Theorem 13.11, one can show this result for the case $f$ is a simple function of a simply connected region (a region is a connected open set). I think that one should take some results in measure theory here, but which results one uses I don't know at my stage of knowledge.

Comment: @DuPhan: The functions $\chi_B$ are usually called characteristic or indicator functions of $B$. Simple functions are finite linear combinations of characteristic functions.

Comment: @DuPhan If you can do it for simple functions then you can do it for all integrable functions since these are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{C})$. To do it for all measurable functions, just do it for the sequence $f_N = f\chi_{B_R}$ (this is just $f$ truncated outside of $B_R$) as I said in my first comment.

Comment: @snarski: There is another difficulty, since the approximation of characteristic functions of balls and/or rectangles given by Runge's theorem is in a.e. convergence, not in $L^1$. If this works in $L^1$, then the rest is standard, true.

Comment: @snarski: I'm sorry. That is my mistake as Lukas Geyer points out (thank you!) Lukas Geyer also notes that the way of convergence is just point-wise (however, for the case $f=\chi_B$, one has the convergence is uniform on compact subsets of $B$.) By the way, I add some of my thoughts in the question, maybe it lets you know my difficulties.

Comment: By the way, the approximation can never work in $L^1$, since any $L^1$-limit of analytic functions would still satisfy a weak mean value property, i.e., the average value over a disk would only depend on the center, not on the radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, by standard measure theory constructions there exists a sequence of simple functions 
$$\phi_n = \sum_{k=1}^{m_n} a_{k,n} \chi_{R_{k,n}}$$
converging to $f$ a.e., where $R_{k,n}$ are open rectangles, $R_{k,n} \cap R_{j,n} = \emptyset$ for $k \ne j$, and such that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{m_n} \overline{R_{k,n}} = [-n,n]^2$. Let
$$\Omega_n := \bigcup_{k=1}^{m_n} R_{k,n}.$$
Then $\Omega_n$ is open with connected complement, $\phi_n$ is analytic on $\Omega_n$, since it is constant on each connected component, and the measure of $[-n,n]^2 \setminus \Omega_n$ is zero. By Runge's approximation theorem there exists a sequence of complex polynomials $P_{j,n}$ with $P_{j,n} \to \phi_n$ locally uniformly on $\Omega_n$ as $j\to\infty$. So there exists a polynomial $P_n = P_{j_n,n}$ such that the measure of the set $$E_n := \left\{ z \in [-n,n]^2 : |P_n(z) - \phi_n(z)| \ge \frac1n\right\}$$ is $\le 2^{-n}$. By a Borel-Cantelli argument this implies that for almost all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ there exists $N=N(z)$ such that $|P_n(z)-\phi_n(z)| < 1/n$ for $n \ge N$. Since $\phi_n \to f$ a.e., this shows $P_n \to f$ a.e.

Comment: Thank you so much for an elegant solution. At first, I trip over three points: the construction of simple functions, the connectness of $\Omega_n^c$ (though it is intuitive), and the Borel-Cantelli argument. After a while, I understand the last two points. For the second point, I make a grid from the rectangles, then prove every vertex must be inside $\Omega_n$ or connected to a fixed point outside; hence get the conclusion for $\Omega_n^c$.

Comment: For the third point, let $A=\{z:\forall N,\exists n\geq N, |P_n(z)-\phi_n(z)|\geq 1/n \}$, then by $A\subset\cap_N\cup_{n\geq N}^{\infty}$, I get your point. But how about the first point, I just read one seemingly relevant result in Rudin's book that every open set is the union of a countable open rectangles. could you elaborate it more for me? Thank you!

Comment: One shows first that every measurable function can be approximated by simple functions, and then that every measurable set can be approximated by open sets (this is called outer regularity of Lebesgue measure), so that arbitrary simple functions can be approximated by simple functions where the sets are all open. Once you are at open sets, you can put a grid on the plane and approximate by rectangles (like you read in Rudin).

Comment: Thank you so much! You teach me a lot! I apply Borel-Cantelli argument for the approximation by open sets (and then by rectangles), and it works.